# Send data from Controller to Razor page

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm currently developing a page where the user can upload an excel file which then gets transfered to a database. I'm using the Radzen framework for file upload and progress bar widgets.

The razor page:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <RadzenUpload Url="upload/single" Style="margin-bottom: 20px;"
                          Progress=@(args => OnProgress(args, "Single file upload")) ChooseText="Datei hochladen...">
            </RadzenUpload>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <h3>Datei-Upload</h3>
            <RadzenProgressBar @bind-Value="progress" Style="margin-bottom: 20px" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
    
        </div>    
    </div>
    <RadzenDataGrid AllowFiltering="true" EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Single" @ref="nowdealsGrid" 
                    IsLoading="@isLoading" AllowColumnResize="true" FilterMode="FilterMode.Simple" 
                    PageSize="25" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" Data="@nowdeals" TItem="Nowdeals" 
                    ColumnWidth="300px" LogicalFilterOperator="LogicalFilterOperator.Or" RowUpdate="@OnUpdateRow" RowCreate="@OnCreateRow">
        <Columns>
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Nowdeals" Property="CommissionNumber" Title="Komm.-Nr" />        
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Nowdeals" Property="Aktionsfahrzeuge" Title="Aktions-Fzg." />            
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Nowdeals" Property="ApprovedByWs" Title="Freigabe WS" />
            <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="Nowdeals" Property="MerbagChipIn" Title="Merbag Chip in" />
            
        </Columns>
    </RadzenDataGrid>
    
    @code{
    
    double progress;
    
    void OnProgress(UploadProgressArgs args, string name)
        {
          

  this.progress = args.Progress;
    }    
}
```

The URL attribute in the `RadzenUpload` component sends the file to my controller:

```
public class UploadController : Controller
{
        private dbContext gwContext;
        public UploadController(dbContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        [HttpPost("upload/single")]
        public IActionResult Single(IFormFile file)
        {
           // Here is where I read from the excel file and write it back to the database               
                  
        }        
}
```

The problem is: the progress bar only shows the status of the actual file upload through its binding to the `progress` variable, which is used by the `RadzenProgressBar`. However, the data transfer to the db (which takes about 6 to 7 seconds) is not included in this step. I would like to have a second progress bar that gives the user a feedback about the progress of the data transfer. So I would have to frequently send back the progress from the controller to the razor page. Is that possible?